# One of 3 elements in a div should variable in size depending on free space

Tags: html, css

I am having a structure like this:

```
<div style="height: 400px">
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
```

The outer div has a fixed height, lets say 400px.
Now I want the first and third child div to use as much of the 400px as they need.
Then the second child div should use the rest of the space, and if there is not enough then a scrollbar should appear.

I am a beginner with this and I would be very thankful for any hints on how this could be done.

Comment: Will the first and third child be under 400px height? Will the total of the first and third child ever need to scroll?

Comment: The first and third child will always be under 400px height. They will never need to scroll.

Comment: if they are a fixed height/known height, this would be a very simple fix. However I recommend you look into `:nth-child()` css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `flexbox` for this. It takes a while to get used to however can achieve some very good results:

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size:20px;
}

.container .box {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container .box-1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.container div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container .box-3 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box-1">box1<br>box1<br>box1<br></div>
  <div class="box box-2">box2<br>box2<br>box2<br>box2<br>box2<br>box2<br>box2<br>box2<br>box2<br>box2<br>box2<br></div>
  <div class="box box-3">box 3</div>
</div>
```